# SQL view creation with prepared statements

Tags: java, sql, view, prepared-statement

I am having trouble generating views based on my code as follows:

```
final String[] clusterClasses = {"exponential", "linear", "periodic"};
java.sql.PreparedStatement pCreateViewStmt = conn.prepareStatement(
    "create view ?_? as "
    + "select * from golden_table where clust_list like ? ?");

for(int i = 0; i < clusterClasses.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < clusterClasses.length; j++) {
        pCreateViewStmt.setString(1, clusterClasses[i]);
        pCreateViewStmt.setString(2, clusterClasses[j]);
        pCreateViewStmt.setString(3, "%"+clusterClasses[i]);
        pCreateViewStmt.setString(4, "%"+clusterClasses[j]+"%");
    }
}
```

I get a SQL Syntax Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''exponential'_'periodic' 
as select * from golden_table where clust_list like '%e' at line 1
```

This has something to do with the PreparedStatement and the wildcards `?` I can't quite figure it out though.

Here is what one iteration of the `i` loop could produce as a create view command:

```sql
create view exponential_periodic AS 
select * 
  from golden_table
  where clust_list like '%exponential%periodic%';
```

Comment: You can't do dynamic queries like that. Prepared statement is used to fill in parameters.

Comment: The problem is that `?` is reserved for parameters in the query, not for a way to set template fields in a query and then exchange these fields for `String`s (or other type of fields). The best in this case would be to use a `StringBuilder` and build the query String, then validate it in case of SQL injection and execute it in your database.

Comment: Could you post or link me to an example? I have heard of a `StringBuilder` but I have no idea what it does or how to use it in this case.

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus Look up its javadoc. Google `StringBuilder [api|javadoc]`